# running different codes when entered from different urls in yii 1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have following code in my php class called Plaint:

```
class Plaint extends CAction
{
    public function run()
    {
        $model = new PlaintForm();
        $this->runTests($model);
        ...........
```

I need to run this class without($this->runTests($model)), if enter from this url `/plaint`. If I enter this page from other url, I need to run  `$this->runTests($model);`.(e.g `/filled`). How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can look for specific phrase in current url:

```
if(strpos(Yii::app()->request->requestUri, '/filled') !== false) {
    $this->runTests($model);
}
```

I advise against putting test code into production code.